# UWP: Using Entity Framework 7 with SQLite cause Heap Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core

I am building UWP application and using Entity Framework 7 (v7.0.0-rc1-final) with SQLite.Net-PCL v3.1.1. Every now and then (unpredictable) I get this **Heap Corruption Exception**. In Visual Studio, I can simply click on button ***continue*** and it continues fine. But in release mode, my application crashed.

I am using lot of background thread to read/write to database. I create lots of new DbContext on each thread

```
using (DbLocal db = new DbLocal())
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

My question is:

> 1. Is creating **DbContext** (ie. in this case **DbLocal**) can cause this problem? I read somewhere, creating **DbContext** is cheap and therefore, each thread can have (and recommended) to create a local **DbContext** (not shared) and dispose it when finish. Is it true?
> 2. What causing this ***Heap Corruption***. My code is simply read from database and write to database and always use a local **DbContext** (never shared - ie. `using (DbLocal db = new DbLocal())`).
> 3. I know there is EF 7 RC2, do you think I should upgrade?

I have been pulling my hair out on with this problem. So, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should be using version 1.1.0 (you are using an old "beta" version) https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/

Comment: @ErikEJ - In my nuget package manager, there is no ***Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite***. But there is ***EntityFramework.Sqlite*** and it is version **v7.0.0-rc1-final**.

Comment: I will try to upgrade to Preview1 and see if the problem disappear. Thanks!

Comment: Then your nuget sources are wrong or nuget manager old

Comment: DBLocal is not SQLite

Comment: @KirstenGreed, my DbLocal is SQLite (perhaps, you may have confused DbLocal with localdb?). Anyway, it only caused problem *every now and then* with Heap Exception. It is still a problem with **v7.0.0-rc1-final**. But I never get around to fix it as I decided to move my app to Android platform.